# ReactJS Combination Advice

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify

I'm learning ReactJS and I want to ask some good combination about the said library, since React is just the view (V), how should we manage the data? 
These are some things I want to know.

1. List of libs/frameworks that can be used with React (along with some brief explanation), it would also be helpful if it's sorted how it should be learned first.
2. Some good starter pack with main build tool are gulp, browserify.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Data management](https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-react#data-managing) section of [Awesome React](https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-react) compilation:

Here is the current list:

- [Immutable.js - Immutable Data Collections for Javascript](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js)
- [cortex - A javascript library for centrally managing data with React](https://github.com/mquan/cortex)
- [avers - A modern client-side model abstraction library](https://github.com/wereHamster/avers)
- [imvvm - Immutable Model-View-ViewModel for React](https://github.com/entrendipity/imvvm)
- [morearty.js - Better state management for React in pure JavaScript](https://github.com/moreartyjs/moreartyjs)
- [valuable - An immutable data store for React](https://github.com/josephsavona/valuable)
- [react-resolver - Isomorphic library to recursively lazy-load data for React components](https://github.com/ericclemmons/react-resolver)
- [freezer-js - Lightweight and reactive immutable data structure for React](https://github.com/arqex/freezer)
- [mobservable - Observable data structures for building reactive React apps](https://github.com/mweststrate/MOBservable)
- [baobab - JavaScript persistent and optionally immutable data tree with cursors](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/baobab)
- [baobab-react - React integration for Baobab](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/baobab-react)
- [datascript - Immutable database and Datalog query engine in ClojureScript](https://github.com/tonsky/datascript)
- [immstruct - Immutable data structures with history for top-to-bottom properties in component based libraries like React](https://github.com/omniscientjs/immstruct)
- [seamless-immutable - Immutable data structures for JavaScript which are backwards-compatible with normal JS Arrays and Objects](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable)

I personally recommend taking a look at Redux - especially the great [introductory lectures](https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux) made available at [Egghead.io](https://egghead.io) by [the author](https://github.com/gaearon) himself.

Alternatively you can also use a standalone model library (like [Ampersand model](https://github.com/ampersandjs/ampersand-model)), or a simpler abstraction for observable data structures (eg [Observable Store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/observable-store)), or in conjugation with an existing MVC framework like Backbone, Spine etc.

Comment: wow! They are sorted right? These are the things that I have to learn in order to build a complete/organize/functional react app? wow! too many! :(